# Regexp query for url matching

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I’ve trouble using the regexp query of elasticsearch.

I want to identify records looking likes this:
"parsed_message": "GET https://server/different-endpoints/fix-endpoint/library.js?m=15f2fe2ddf0, Referrer=https://url.com"

I’ve read https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html and learned that elasticsearch regex matching works a bit different. But according to what I read I played around and found out that

```
GET logs-*/_search
{
  "query": {
      "regexp": {
        "parsed_message": ".*\\.js.*"
      }
  }
}
```

actually finds results. Since this expression is way to rough, I tried

```
GET logs-*/_search
{
  "query": {
      "regexp": {
        "parsed_message": ".*\\.js\\?.*"
      }
  }
}
```

to make it a bit more precise. But even after this little change the query does not match anymore. What am I doing wrong?

Best regards,
BK

Comment: Maybe `".*?fix-endpoint.*?\\.js.*"`